# How to user "merge" in entity framework code first to merge the multiple result set from a stored procedure into one single collection

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to entity framework. I have a simple stored procedure that returns 2 result set.

I am using a code-first approach and need to merge the 2 result set into one single collection using "merge". I don't want to modify my stored procedure.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do the result sets have the same shape?  Do you have Entity definitions that map to the result sets?

Comment: Yes the result set have the same shape and yes the entity definitions map to the result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the doc here:

[Entity Framework Sprocs with Multiple Result Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx)

Except in your case both DataReaders load the same entity.

eg

```
    var foos1= ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
        .ObjectContext
        .Translate<Foo>(reader, "Foos", MergeOption.AppendOnly);   

    // Move to second result set and read next set of entities
    reader.NextResult();
    var foos2 = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
        .ObjectContext
        .Translate<Foo>(reader, "Foos", MergeOption.AppendOnly);

    var foos = foos1.Union(foos2).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi David, I have one more question that I have posted on a different post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274737/entity-framework-code-first-approach-creating-entities-using-tpt-inheritance , If you have any idea about it kindly let me know. Thanks.